# Are JNI native invocations from different Java threads sequentialized?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, concurrency, java-native-interface

I am making a Windows JNI .dll. I am trying to determine whether the JVM can ever make concurrent calls to the same native function. Here is the Java code I wrote:

```
public class TestThreads implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        MyJNIClass.f(); // Call 'native' static member function
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 20; ++k)
            new Thread(new TestThreads()).run();
    }
}
```

On the native side, the function `MyJNIClass.f()` is implemented like so:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNIClass_f(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz)
    {
        std::cout << GetCurrentThreadId() << ", " << GetCurrentThread() << std::endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

The output from the native function indicates that all the calls are running from the same Win32 thread:

> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> 5196, 0xfffffffe
> ...

...and each of these lines pops out about half a second after the previous one.

So is the only way to get the native side to use multiple threads like the JVM to create a worker thread on the native/DLL side and then return immediately!?!?

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'sequentialized', not 'serialized', which nowadays means something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only one thread which is "main"  which was created for you.

I suspect you intended to call `start();` which calls `run();` in a new thread, instead of reusing the current thread.

Comment: Oh man, do I feel foolish -- I hope nobody downvotes me for rank ignorance! As soon as I substitute `start()` for `run()`, I see different threads on the Windows DLL side. So basically, I wasn't multithreading on the Java side, let alone the Windows side, before. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add, JNI isn't serialized, you can call from multiple threads.